# Docker access by container IP not working but is accessible through localhost

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile, devops

I have been learning docker and one thing I learned is that if a port is exposed in a container and an application is running at that port then you can access it using `http://container_IP:port` which I have tested and it always works.

But today while doing the same with an Angular app, I found that I can't access the URL and it does not return anything.
**Magically** I thought of hitting `http://localhost:port` and it worked, how is this possible and why did it even happen in the first place?

**Dockerfile**

```
# Stage 1

FROM node as build-step

RUN mkdir -p /app

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.*json /app

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

# RUN npm install -g ts-node

RUN npm run build

# Stage 2

FROM nginx

EXPOSE 80

COPY --from=build-step /app/dist/test-app /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use container IP address
that's why you are exposing the `port` because you want to map `container` port to `localhost` port

Comment: But then why can I access certain apps with container IP? I thought exposing had to do with exposing the port on container itself since all ports by default on containers are locked?

Comment: @VanWilder Think of a container as another form of virtualization. Basically it is an OS with IP, Network and everything...

Comment: @VanWilder I guess you cant access your container because you deleted it and recreated it, you can never depend on container IP

Comment: I have been trying to access it after checking its IP every time. On top of that what if there were multiple containers running multiple apps on the same port, isn't porting to localhost bad then?
The thing is, I used a react app and I could access it using the container IP, I just can't seem to do it with the angular one?

Comment: @VanWilder no it isnt bad that's why you can map ports https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#published-ports

Comment: It's implementation dependent if it works or not. It doesn't work on Windows with WSL for instance. You shouldn't use it.

Comment: It happens to work because you're on a native-Linux host and the client is on the same host as the container.  It won't work in any other environment.